# Derive equations for the roll, pitch, and yaw angles?

Tags: linear-algebra, robotics

How to derive equations for the roll, pitch, and yaw angles corresponding to the rotation matrix R having ijth element rij?

Comment: The order that the rotations are done is important. In the calibration process I do for telematic devices we use pitch, roll yaw. Do you specifically want roll, pitch yaw ?

Comment: Yes, I need it in the order of roll, pitch, and yaw angles.

Comment: Do you want to derive the three elementary rotations also, or are you assuming they are sufficiently defined?

Comment: I feel like if you first read about rotation matrices in general your question will be answered. It seems like you want to be spoon fed the trigonometry and linear algebra needed understand how to compose roll/pitch/yaw from three elementary rotations $\mathrm{R} = R_z\,R_y\,R_x$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking forward-backwards as the $x$-axis and roll is rotations about the $x$- axis
\begin{eqnarray*}
R_x(r)= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & \cos(r) & \sin(r) \\
0 & -\sin(r) & \cos(r) \\
\end{array} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Taking left-right as the $y$-axis and pitch is rotations about the $y$-axis
\begin{eqnarray*}
R_y(p)= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(p) & 0 & -\sin(p)  \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sin(p) & 0 & \cos(p) \\
\end{array} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Taking up-down as the $z$-axis and yaw is rotations about the $z$-axis
\begin{eqnarray*}
R_z(y) =\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(y) & \sin(y) & 0  \\
-\sin(y) & \cos(y) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1  
\end{array}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Do the matrix multiplication ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
R_z(y) R_y(p) R_x(r) = \\ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(y) \cos(p) & \cos(y)\sin(p)\sin(r)+\sin(y)\cos(r) & -\cos(y)\sin(p)\cos(r)+\sin(y)\sin(r)  \\
-\sin(y\cos(p)) & -\sin(y)\sin(p)\sin(r)+\cos(y)\cos(r) & \sin(y)\sin(p)\cos(r)+\cos(y)\cos(r) \\
\sin(p) & \sin(r)\cos(p) & \cos(p)\cos(r) 
\end{array} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Your rotation matrix should have the structure above. The angles can be deduced from the following formulea
\begin{eqnarray*}
p =\sin^{-1}( R_{1,3}) \\
r= \cos^{-1}(\frac{R_{3,3}}{\cos(p)}) \\
y= \cos^{-1}(\frac{R_{1,1}}{\cos(p)}) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
You should check the other component satisfy this structure.